# How replace city text box in shipping address with select component in drupal 7 commerce

Tags: commerce, entities

I want to know, is there any way to change city textbox in shipping address (in Drupal commerce 7) to select component?

in normal mode, user have to write the name of city but I want to change it to select field so user can select a city between available items in select field.

Also I want to add another select field to address that contains provinces.

Comment: Is this for a particular country? If so, you could do it with an addressfield country plugin.

Comment: Dear David, addressfield country plugin is different from address field module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In drupal several module can solved your problem:

https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield_vn

https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield_cl

https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield_peru

https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield_ro

https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield_hu

you can choose on of them and edit for your country. for example in addressfield_vn change country code «VN» to your country code. and add your province and city name to module.
for iran address i create a module. if you want then email to me.